# GPS Maps dont sowt it

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-gps

I'm doing an app gps to localize me in maps, so I'm using a phone with android version 8.1, and it intalled in my phone without problem, buy don't show me the maps.

lock like it show in my phone:
[image: screenshots]

this is my build.gradle(module app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ejemplogpsmaps"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'

}
```

this is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMensaje"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Ubicacion"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.example.ejemplogpsmaps.FragmentMaps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvMensaje" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

this MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.ejemplogpsmaps;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvMensaje;

    // Minimo tiempo para updates en Milisegundos
    private static final long MIN_TIME = 10000; // 10 segundos

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvMensaje = findViewById(R.id.tvMensaje);

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);

        } else {
            iniciarLocalizacion();
        }
    }

    private void iniciarLocalizacion() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Localizacion local = new Localizacion();

        local.setMainActivity(this, tvMensaje);

        final boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(!gpsEnabled) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
            return;
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, local);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, local);

        tvMensaje.setText("Localizacion agregada");
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[]grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == 1000) {
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                iniciarLocalizacion();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thid AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ejemplogpsmaps">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="UNY GPS"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="I hide my key" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I hide my key API for segurity.

this FragmentMaps.java

```
package com.example.ejemplogpsmaps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class FragmentMaps extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    double lat, lon;

    public FragmentMaps() { }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
        View rootView = super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, bundle);

        if(getArguments() != null) {
            this.lat = getArguments().getDouble("lat");
            this.lon = getArguments().getDouble("lon");
        }

        getMapAsync(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);

        float zoom = 17;

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));

        UiSettings settings = googleMap.getUiSettings();

        settings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

this localizacion.java

```
package com.example.ejemplogpsmaps;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {

    MainActivity mainActivity;
    TextView tvMensaje;

    public MainActivity getMainActivity() {
        return mainActivity;
    }

    public void setMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity, TextView tvMensaje) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        this.tvMensaje = tvMensaje;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Este metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS recibe nuevas coordenadas
        String texto = "Mi ubicación es: \n"
                + "Latitud = " + location.getLatitude() + "\n"
                + "Longitud = " + location.getLongitude();

        tvMensaje.setText(texto);

        mapa(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    }

    public void mapa(double lat, double lon) {
        // Fragment del Mapa
        FragmentMaps fragment = new FragmentMaps();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putDouble("lat", new Double(lat));
        bundle.putDouble("lon", new Double(lon));
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getMainActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment, fragment, null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.AVAILABLE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        tvMensaje.setText("GPS Activado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        tvMensaje.setText("GPS Desactivado");
    }
}
```

so, I created this project like Google Maps Activity and add 
permissions to access fine location in AndroidManifest.xml.

so yo can help me please, I don't undersant

Comment: First let's rule out the basics. Do you have billing enabled on your project? Is Maps SDK for Android enabled too? Is your API key properly restricted?

Comment: Hey Hello! I found the solution, it was changing the API_KEY and it work!

Comment: Thanks for your update, glad to hear! Please consider answering your own question and accepting it for the community's sake. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was changing the API_KEY, I created a new Key and paste here:

```
       <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="NEW_API_key" />
```